# Magento: Multiple Thumbnails

Tags: php, image, magento, thumbnails, product

I want to have two different product box-templates in my Magento shop: One for category views and one for cross-and upselling. Both of them should use different thumbnails. How can I manage that?

Comment: please explain it with little more detail

Comment: The product thumbnail of the upselling-box should be another than in the regular product box

Comment: You can add media attribute and show this images instead of default images